# Cannot view files on amazon s3 git repo after using jgit to push

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jgit

I am using jgit to push files into my amazon s3 bucket. I followed this guide and everything seems to work. I was able to push my repo.

http://blog.spearce.org/2008/07/using-jgit-to-publish-on-amazon-s3.html

But when I look into my s3 bucket, I don't see any of the files I pushed. I only see git specific files, .pack, .idx, HEAD, config, etc. How do you actually view the files you pushed?

Comment: If you don't see the files in S3 then it isn't actually pushing them to S3.

Comment: I was thinking the files are actually git formatted files so you don't see the actual files. I am able to clone from s3 but I cannot use those files directly in s3.

Comment: If you can clone then I guess everything is there. The whole scenario of using S3 as a git repo seems strange to me. If you need specific help on jgit's usage of S3 then your best bet is probably to post your question on the official jgit forum.